# Undefined control sequence in page setup

Tags: errors

I imported a page setup which looks like this

```
\parident{0cm}
\parident{0cm}
\hypernation
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hypenpenalty=10000
```

Errors "Undefined control sequence"

Is there need to add a package?

Comment: `\parident` isn't defined by default nor is `hypernation` I'd expect you to get errors from each of the first three lines `\hyphenpenalty` is defined but then the last line has  `\hypenpenalty` which is again not defined and presumably a typo for the 3rd line.

Comment: There's no default `\parident`, `\hypernation` nor `\hypenpenalty` definitions. You're probably looking for `\parindent`, `\hyphenation` and `\hyphenpenalty`. There's no need to perform the same things twice though.

Answer (score 2):

```
\parident{0cm}
```

there is no `\parident` command (in any package that I know) most likely `\parindent` was intended but that has a different syntax

```
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
```

or using lower level syntax

```
\parindent=0cm
```

---

```
\parident{0cm}
```

This is the same as the previous line, so delete.

---

```
\hypernation
```

This is presumably a typo for `\hyphenation` but that has a mandatory list of words to hyphenate `\hyphenation{foo-bar}` so just delete this line.

---

```
\hyphenpenalty=10000
```

This is the one line without a syntax error and would disable hyphenation in the document.

---

```
\hypenpenalty=10000
```

Presumably this is a typo for `\hyphenation` but if you fix that it is the same as the previous line so simply delete this.

---

Given that 4 out of 5 lines have syntax errors a simpler thing might be not to "import the page setup" from wherever you got it. It does not seem a reliable source.

Comment: +1 for "Given that 4 out of 5 lines have syntax errors a simpler thing might be not to 'import the page setup' from wherever you got it."

Comment: Thank you for the information. I'll comment the page setup and try to reproduce from a decent site

Comment: @kevin The page setup is already done by the class. You don't need to copy any  code from anywhere. If you really need to add hyphenation rules, you can do so. If you need to change the page margins from the default, use package `geometry`  and its features.

Comment: @Johannes_B I have removed the page setup and only added the hyphenation. I tried the geometry and found it satisfying Thank you for advice, sir